# Why do you have to append a : when sending a message?

Tags: ruby

When sending a method to a reciever like:

```
method_name = :"#{some_method}"

send(method_name) if respond_to?(method_name, true)
```

Does the : mean that it is a symbol of sort?

Answer (score 3):

Symbols in Ruby can contain any string value, but cannot be represented using the literal `:xxx` notation unless `xxx` is a valid identifier. For Symbols that are not valid identifiers, or when you want to use string interpolation to create the symbol, you specify them with the notation `:"yyy"` and Ruby also reports them as such:

```
irb(main):001:0> "foo".to_sym
=> :foo
irb(main):002:0> :foo
=> :foo
irb(main):003:0> "foo-bar".to_sym
=> :"foo-bar"
irb(main):004:0> :"foo-bar"
=> :"foo-bar"
```

What you have above, :"#{some_method}", is the same as `some_method.to_s.to_sym`.

As noted in my comments to other posts, however, you can pass a string directly to `send` instead of a symbol, if you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the docs on this.
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M001005

Yes it does require a symbol, which means that you can also call, which is easier on the eyes.

```
send(method_name) if respond_to?(some_method.to_sym, true)
```

Comment: Actually, no, it does not require a symbol (tested in 1.8.6, 1.8.7, 1.9.1, and 1.9.2): `[].send('length') #=> 0`